# Return string of pre selected words from another string with PHP

Tags: php, string

I got a string with a product name. This string is also containing colors.

Example: "Red T-Shirt White Yellow Stripes Black Dots" ($productname)

The PHP function should now return all colors of the t-shirt in a string.

I think I know how to return one color, for example red:

```
if (stripos($productname, 'red') !== false) {
    return 'red';
}
```

How can I return a string with all colors (comma seperated)? In this case it should be "red, white, yellow, black". I've got a list of 30 different colors.

Can someone give me a hint?

Thanks!

Comment: Create a regexp and use `preg_match_all`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all - you need to know what colors to find.

So, your colors array **must be** defined:

```
$colors = ['red', 'white', 'black', 'yellow', 'green'];
// create a regexp pattern from this array
// add `i` flag for turning off case sensistivity
$colors_regexp = '/(' . implode('|', $colors) . ')/i';    
$matches = [];
$string = 'Red T-Shirt White Yellow Stripes Black Dots';
preg_match_all($colors_regexp, $string, $matches);
// print_r `$matches` to see the matches:
echo'<pre>',print_r($matches),'</pre>';
// use proper key from `$matches`:
echo implode(', ', $matches[0]);    // `Red, White, Yellow, Black`
```

Going further - you can add `\b` which means `word boundary` so as other words like `whitened` or `blackened` will not match your regexp:

```
preg_match_all(
    '/\b(black|white|red)\b/i', 
    'White or red blackened item', 
    $matches
);
// matches[0] shows: `Array( [0] => White [1] => red )`, no `black`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can use a foreach loop to check the if you already got going for every single colour, like so:

```
function check_colour($productname){

    $colours = new array("Red", "White", "Yellow", "Black", "Green");

    foreach ($colours as $colour) {
        if (stripos($productname, $colour) !== false) {
            $output .= $colour.",";
        }
    }
    $out = rtrim($output, ',');

    return $out
}

$productname = "Red T-Shirt White Yellow Stripes Black Dots";

echo check_colour($productname);
```

I put it in a function to easily be capable of calling it, you can also make it that the colours are also an argument:

```
function check_colour($productname, $colours){

    foreach ($colours as $colour) {
        if (stripos($productname, $colour) !== false) {
            $output .= $colour.",";
        }
    }
    $out = rtrim($output, ',');

    return $out
}

$productname = "Red T-Shirt White Yellow Stripes Black Dots";

$colours = new array("Red", "White", "Yellow", "Black", "Green");

echo check_colour($productname);
```

EDIT:
rtrim() removes the last comma

Answer (score 0):

A different approach since we are using an array of colors, just create an array of words from the string and find the intersection (common words). Use `array_map()` to make the cases the same for case-insensitivity:

```
$string = "Red T-Shirt White Yellow Stripes Dots";
$colors = array("Red", "White", "Yellow", "Black");

$result = array_intersect(array_map('strtolower', $colors),
                          array_map('strtolower', explode(' ', $string)));

print_r($result);
//or
echo implode(', ', $result);
```

This splits the string by 1 space.  If you have multiple spaces, tabs or newlines etc. use this instead of `explode()`:

```
preg_split('/\s+/', $string);
```